# Android - ADB command to perform Drag and drop action?

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to perform drag and drop action using adb command.

For appium This is how we do: 
'''
action.longPress(ele1).moveTo(ele2).release().perform();
'''

I would like to do this for android using adb command.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command:

```
adb shell input draganddrop x1 y1 x2 y2
```

If several devices are connected, use:

```
adb -s serialno shell input draganddrop x1 y1 x2 y2
```